# Cannot Get Values from my Function to my update.php

Tags: javascript, php, api

So i cant receive the values from my function to update my database, the code is working if i manually put the values.

My function

```
   function changeStatus(id, ativo) {
        $.post(baseUrl + "article_type/update.php",
            {
                id: id,
                ativo: ativo
            },
    
            function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
    }
```

My update api

```
<?php
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization,X-Requested-With');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Articles_type.php';
  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  // Set ID to UPDATE
$data = [
    'ativo' => $data->ativo,
    'id' => $data->id,
];
$sql = "UPDATE tipo_artigos SET ativo=:ativo WHERE id=:id";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
 
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the POST header?     `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST');`

Comment: tried, still no result

Comment: Manually put the values where? What issue are you encountering with this code? Why `header('Content-Type: application/json');`? You're just doing a regular `post` (you're not sending JSON explicitly).

Comment: if i change this values ativo' => $data->ativo,
    'id' => $data->id, manually it works, im using that because i was testing more things

Comment: Alright, allow the `POST` method, remove the `Content-Type` header and take values from `$_POST` instead of reading from input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked me, if you think it is right format you can follow:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  //header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization,X-Requested-With'); 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  // Set ID to UPDATE
$data = [
    'ativo' => $_POST['ativo'],
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
];
```

Comment: Note that `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` is no longer necessary here.

Comment: Yes Absolutely, and also  remove header everything( check if not required), There is no use, if we follow these type of format code!